# Jquery split variable back from PHP json (checkbox:checked)

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

In this code jquery get the data back from php and i would like to get jquery explode one of the variable where multiple auto are stored and finally get the specific checkbox checked

json_reponse_from_PHP: "auto1; auto3; auto4".

```
$(document).on("click", "#update", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var datas = 'pg/post.php';
    $.getJSON(datas, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
            $('input[name=' + key + '], select[name=' + key + '], textarea[name=' + key + ']').val(value);                  
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
</div>
```

See example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" checked="checked" value="auto1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" value="auto2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" checked="checked" value="auto3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" checked="checked" value="auto4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" value="auto5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="auto[]" value="auto6" />
```

Can you help me to find

Comment: Given that you appear to be returning a semi-colon delimited list of values, what are you expecting to happen with the `key` and `value` variables in your JS?

Comment: Key is the variable name in PHP and the input name in my form. the data becomes sent on the specific input. but i would like to add some checkbox input to get them checked form a variable like "auto1; auto3; auto5"
sorry fo my english...

Comment: Why wouldn't you send as array? Very strange to only json_encode a delimited string

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan mentioned, I don't see how you expected to get 2 values out of a single list of semicolon separated values,  this part `.val(value)` doesn't make sense to me. But for the try  `$.each(data.split(';'), function( key ) {` but from the looks of it you want to check things based on values. which makes this `$('input[name=' + key + ']:checkbox').prop('checked', true);$('select[name=' + key + '], textarea[name=' + key + ']').val(key);` seems to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a checkbox you don't use `val()` you use `prop('checked', true)`

Since you have array naming on elements you can't match the specific name so you will need to use the returned value to help target the checkboxes.

Also what you are sending from server doesn't match the names anyway.

```
$.each(data.split(';'), function(_, val ) {
     $(':input[value=' + val +']').prop('checked',true);
});
```

It makes no sense either not to send array from server instead of json_encoding a delimited string in your php